# Xam.Plugin.Filepicker not doing anything after picking file

Tags: xamarin.forms, filepicker

I am using [Xam.Plugin.FilePicker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.FilePicker) for picking the file in my Xamarin.Forms app. (I'm using a PCL project and added reference to all projects).

This is my button for calling the event:

```
<Button Text="Select" Clicked="Upload_Button_Clicked"/>
```

And this is my click handler:

```
private async void Upload_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileData fileData = new FileData();
    fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
    if(fileData != null)
    {
        byte[] data = fileData.DataArray;
        current_filename.Text = fileData.FileName;
    }
}
```

It does open the file browser and after picking the file, the await method doesn't get completed. I mean I put the breakpoint after this line

`fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();`

However, the breakpoint never hits and when I try to pick the file again it gives an exception as if the await method was still running.

**EDIT**

I was adding JPG image when I'm facing this issue. Now, I tried to add a PDF file and the next breakpoint was hit. The fileName is coming, but `byte[]` is empty.

Comment: have you tried by picking up a file with very small amount of size like in bytes just to test, it can be size issue.

Comment: Yes i was picking small jpgs

Comment: I was adding jpg image when im facing this issue.. Now i tried adding a PDF file , Now next breakpoint got hit.fileName is comming.But byte[] is empt